# Create an edit window that pulls info from previous window ListView

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

I am new to programming (6 months or so). I am working on a basic application for fun and GUI experience in JavaFX. I am currently looking for a way to open a "View/Edit Account" screen. I a previous window, I have a listview box that displays the names of accounts that i have in an arraylist (Im using text files as a way to save, as i havent ventured into SQL yet). The goal is to be able to click on the name of an array object, hit edit, and that new window opens up some GUI with more thorough details about the object you just clicked on, and even allow you to edit the variables. I currently utilize the selectionmode methods that are built in with javaFX to load the objext i click on into a person variable, i just dont know how to get that to carry over to a new dialog window. Here is some of my code (Is the listView windows controller) p.s. i apologize if its sloppy. Ive had a lot of trial and error:

```
public class accountController {


public List<accountObj> myList;
@FXML
private ListView<accountObj> test;

@FXML
AnchorPane newAccountPane;

public void  initialize () { //initializes the code. Seems similar to a main class
    test.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<accountObj>() {//adds a listener to update the info of what is selected
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends accountObj> observable, accountObj oldValue, accountObj newValue) {
            if (newValue != null) {//means if something is selected then it pulls in the info of what is selected in the list
                accountObj person = test.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();


            }
        }
    });

    test.setItems(DataTwo.getInstanceTwo().getAccountObjs());
    test.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    test.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
}
    @FXML
    public void handleClicktest () {
        accountObj person = (accountObj) test.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();



    }
        public void showViewAccount() {//shows the new account screen.
            Dialog<ButtonType> dialog2 = new Dialog<>();
            dialog2.initOwner(newAccountPane.getScene().getWindow());
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader2 = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader2.setLocation(getClass().getResource("viewAccount.fxml"));
            try {
                dialog2.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader2.load());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Couldnt load the dialog");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            dialog2.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);//these add the ok and cancel buttons to the window
            dialog2.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);

            Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog2.showAndWait();
            if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                viewAccountController controller = fxmlLoader2.getController();


            }}


        public void showNewAccount() {//shows the new account screen.
            Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
            dialog.initOwner(newAccountPane.getScene().getWindow());
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("newAccount.fxml"));
            try {
                dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Couldnt load the dialog");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);//these add the ok and cancel buttons to the window
            dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);
            Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
            if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                newAccountController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
                accountObj newPerson=controller.processResults2();
                test.getSelectionModel().select(newPerson);
            }
        }
```

Comment: In the method `handleClicktest()` you assign the selected item to the variable `person`, but you don't use it afterwards. Are you asking how you can pass this `person` variable to a new dialog window?

Comment: @Dryr yes! That is exactly what i mean! Thank you for wording it better than i could. I want to be able and view the person variable in a new dialog pane. The goal is to be able to view the name, address, email, and account number on this window (i already have the FXML all made, it just populates with no info), and edit the info for it (Ill worry about this particular part after this task is solved). Each person variable that would be clicked on contain the above listed attributes.

Comment: https://github.com/JayHelton/Business_Management

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration of the `showViewAccount` method to

```
public void showViewAccount(accountObj person)
```

Next, in the body of the `handleClicktest` method, you can pass the `person` argument to the `showViewAccount` method
It should look like this

```
public void handleClicktest () {
    accountObj person = (accountObj) test.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    showViewAccount(person);
}
```